# Python poetry: adding the --allow-prereleases flag to an already installed package

Tags: python, python-poetry

By mistake I added **black** to my poetry environment along with all other dependencies without the **--allow-prereleases** flag.

If I try to do it now I get:

```
(rssita-py3.10) (base) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini rssita % poetry add --group dev black --allow-prereleases**
The following packages are already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped:

  • black

If you want to update it to the latest compatible version, you can use `poetry update package`.
If you prefer to upgrade it to the latest available version, you can use `poetry add package@latest`.

Nothing to add.
```

How would I be able to add that option to only black either via command line poetry commands or editing the **pyproject.toml** file manually? Here's the current version:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "rssita"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Robert Alexander <gogonegro@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "rssita", from = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
stanza = "^1.4.2"
feedparser = "^6.0.10"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
pre-commit = "^3.0.2"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^0.991"
isort = "^5.12.0"
black = "^22.12.0"
requests = "^2.28.2"
types-requests = "^2.28.11.8"
pylint = "^2.16.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.isort]
multi_line_output = 3
include_trailing_comma = true
force_grid_wrap = 0
use_parentheses = true
line_length = 79

[tool.black]
line-length = 79
target-version = ['py310']
include = '.pyi?$'
exclude = '''

(
  /(
      .eggs         # exclude a few common directories in the
    | .git          # root of the project
    | .hg
    | .mypy_cache
    | .tox
    | .venv
    | _build
    | buck-out
    | build
    | dist
  )/
  | foo.py           # also separately exclude a file named foo.py in
                     # the root of the project
)
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Just first remove black from the dependencies:

```
poetry remove black
```

then add it back with the proper syntax:

```
poetry add --group dev black --allow-prereleases
```

and this will fix both pyproject.toml and poetry.lock